# QT Including types from class header

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on QT 5.0 on OSX. I've included header files from other classes but using those classes as a type gives an error on building: use of undeclared identifier.

However, some classes I included do seem to be able to use as a type. Could it be a bug in QT or did I miss something?

Thanks

Code example:

```
#include Aclass.h

class Bclass { vector<Aclass> vectorofA;}
```

Comment: Option #2 ("did I miss something") is much more likely. Do you have any circular dependencies, for example is `#include "Bclass.h"` found within `Aclass.h`?

Comment: Could you post a minimal real code example for us to follow?

Comment: is a type named Aclass in Aclass.h defined?

Comment: Where is `;` at the end of `Bclass` declaration?

Comment: Thanks all, it seemed there were circular dependencies. I'm gonna read up on this subject so I won't mess things up in the future :-)